# How should I properly deal with inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I'll take sine as an example for this question.

I've always taken $ \arcsin(x) $ as a single-valued function, however reading Wolfram MathWorld's page on "Inverse Sine" (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html) I've found that it is actually multi-valued, and $ \operatorname{Arcsin}(x) $ is typically how we write the single-valued version of it.

My question is: is it more correct to treat $ \arcsin(x) $ as a set of values, so that if we have $ y = \sin(x) $, then $ x \in \arcsin(x) $, rather than $ x = \arcsin(x) $?

And, as a side question, is there a reason why Wolfram Alpha's plot of $ y = \arcsin(x) $ treats the function as single-valued, despite Wolfram MathWorld's statement that it is multi-valued?

Comment: Treat it the same way you treat the square root.  Or the logarithm.

Comment: Suppose you have function $f: D \to R$ and define inverse as $f^{-1}(r)=\{d \in D: f(d)=r, r\in R\}$, then it's certainly possible that $f^{-1}$ might not be a function. For example, consider $f(x)=x^2$. The inverse would be $\pm \sqrt x$ (multi-valued). If you would like inverse to be a proper function, you'd somehow have to make it single-valued.

Comment: In complex analysis : take $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ complex analytic and $a \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f'(a) \ne 0$. Then for $|z-a|$ small enough $f$ is injective (bijective) and you can define its local inverse function $f^{-1}(s)$ which is analytic for $|s-f(a)|$ small enough. Then you can look at the analytic continuation of $f^{-1}$ which will be multi-valued (branch points) if $f$ is not globally injective. Note how taking $f(z) = z^2, \exp(z), \sin(z)$ gives the multi-valued functions $f^{-1}(s) = s^{1/2},\log s, \text{arcsin}(s)$